# WPF ColorAnimation Blinks

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

Every time I hover on the button, the background blinks then animates/goes to the color I chose, like this:
[image]

this is my style:

```xml
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border x:Name="Bg" Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.25" Storyboard.TargetName="Bg" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="#1E1E1E"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.25" Storyboard.TargetName="Bg" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Transparent"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </Trigger.ExitActions>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Nevermind, I found out the solution, setting it to Transparent causes it, so I replaced it with "#00000000" which is transparent (its basically the color's opacity to 0)

Comment: I was unable to get the effect you are describing. Your animation works for me as intended. A mistake in something else.

Comment: It blinks then goes to the color i chose, how do i remove the blink?

Comment: It doesn't blink for me.
Perhaps the problem is not in the animation, but in the layout of the elements.
You animate the color between transparent white (# 00FFFFFF) and opaque almost black ("# FF1E1E1E).
During the animation of Transparent, the elements behind the button can be seen.